# Failed to connect before deadline

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, grpc, hyperledger-fabric-ca

When I run `query.js` (similar to `query.js` in `fabcar` but modified for my application), I keep getting an error which says,

> Failed to connect before the deadline

I have changed the localhost to docker IP address in `enrollAdmin.js` and `registerUser.js`

TLS is enabled for peer, orderer and cli.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem. These steps fixed it for me:

- Open VirtualBox Manager and select the “default” VM
- Click “Settings”, “Network”, “Advanced”, “Port Forwarding”.
- Create a new rule by clicking the “+” sign on the right and entering the following: Name -> “grpc”, Host Port -> 7051, Guest Port -> 7051
- You can leave the Host IP and Guest IP unspecified.

Thx to: https://developer.ibm.com/opentech/2017/11/29/running-hyperledger-fabric-windows-revised/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem:

I think grpc and fabric-client package has issues or different versions than we need (verify the package.json for npm) . Therefore I decided to manually install the latest versions of the npm fabric-ca-client, fabric-client and grpc packages  and it worked!!!!

I hope this solution works for you!!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as well

What works for me is that I reinstall the global window-build-tools and global grpc, and it works afterwards. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was changing the localhost to Docker's IP(seen when the docker terminal starts) in the network connections file(either connections.json or networkConnections.yaml) being used in the query.js(or any other js).